# Pulling other images except first from JSON object with Vue

Tags: json, vuejs2, graphql, gridsome

I'm trying to get the second image url within a JSON object using Vue. I can get the first image src url by specifying `<img :src="item.images[0].url" />`. So, logically, I thought `<img :src="item.images[1].url" />` would get the second image (300x300) variation. It doesn't.

**(Update)** I just realized I need a `v-if` because not all playlists have the 300x300 image size.

How do I write if has `images[1].url` else `images[0].url`?

My for loop:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in $page.oneGraph.spotify.me.playlists" :key="index">
```

Here's what my query returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "spotify": {
      "me": {
        "id": "me",
        "playlists": [
          {
            "id": "5EpTRIeVs55Hl1g7NY53v1",
            "name": "Euphrate",
            "images": [
              {
                "url": "https://mosaic.scdn.co/640/ab67616d0000b27320a15cbf156f65c94ef6a506ab67616d0000b27365db2b50dcd76741d9fa12a5ab67616d0000b27377d36619ec51d9f76bb1ffcfab67616d0000b2739d24c92c3d3837eb9366cb79",
                "height": 640,
                "width": 640
              },
              {
                "url": "https://mosaic.scdn.co/300/ab67616d0000b27320a15cbf156f65c94ef6a506ab67616d0000b27365db2b50dcd76741d9fa12a5ab67616d0000b27377d36619ec51d9f76bb1ffcfab67616d0000b2739d24c92c3d3837eb9366cb79",
                "height": 300,
                "width": 300
              },
              {
                "url": "https://mosaic.scdn.co/60/ab67616d0000b27320a15cbf156f65c94ef6a506ab67616d0000b27365db2b50dcd76741d9fa12a5ab67616d0000b27377d36619ec51d9f76bb1ffcfab67616d0000b2739d24c92c3d3837eb9366cb79",
                "height": 60,
                "width": 60
              }
            ],
…
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code that you've shared, if `<img :src="item.images[0].url" />` works then `<img :src="item.images[1].url" />` should work as well.

Most likely what's happening is that one of the `playlists` in your json only has one image which causes your code to error when you try to access the second image.

To fix this, you could add a `v-if` like below:

`<img :src="item.images[1].url" v-if="item.images.length > 1" />`

Comment: Yes, it was erroring out because one of the smaller images didn't exist, but the error wasn't specific enough. I figured out an amateurish way of writing it: `<img v-if="item.images[1]" :src="item.images[1].url" />
<img v-else :src="item.images[0].url" />`. I want to say if second image exists, use it, else use the first image. But, there's probably a more efficient way.

Comment: You could try `<img :src="(item.images[1] || item.images[0]).url" />`

Comment: That's better yet. Thanks  @shoejep